# Visual Studio 2005 context menu launches server explorer: why?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

For some reason, a variety of actions in Visual Studio 2005, actions that have nothing to do with SQL Server, are opening the "Connect to SQL Server" dialog. And it takes four (4) clicks on the CANCEL button to kill the dialog.

For example, if I right click on a class method in the Editor, hoping to find the Go To Definition option, the dialog opens.

Or if I run a project in Debug mode, and then close the app, the dialog opens.

I have to close VS and re-open it to get this to stop. But after a while, this behavior returns. What is causing it has eluded me.

Is this Microsoft's way to get me to upgrade to VS2008? OK, he's had VS2005 for too long. Time for him to upgrade. Invoke DriveCustomerMad.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you see the dialog box, open a second copy of VS2005, attach its debugger to the first one, pause the process, and look at the call stack.

Do you have any addons installed?